# Loop through dropdown list, picking a different option each time

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm new to selenium, and I am trying to write a script to create accounts on the website, each time picking a different option from a particular dropdown list.

Here is the website code:

```html
<div id="boundlist-1133" class="x-boundlist x-boundlist-floating x-layer x-boundlist-default x-border-box" tabindex="-1" style="right: auto; left: 374px; top: 164px; height: 288px; z-index: 19001;">
 <div id="boundlist-1133-listEl" class="x-boundlist-list-ct x-unselectable" style="overflow: auto; height: 288px;">
  <ul class="x-list-plain">
   <li class="x-boundlist-item x-boundlist-selected" role="option"><none></li>
   <li class="x-boundlist-item" role="option">QA1BILLINGPLAN01</li>
   <li class="x-boundlist-item" role="option">QA1BILLINGPLAN03</li>
   <li class="x-boundlist-item" role="option">QA1BILLINGPLAN04</li>
   <li class="x-boundlist-item" role="option">QA1BILLINGPLAN08</li>
   <li class="x-boundlist-item" role="option">QA1BILLINGPLAN09</li>
   <li class="x-boundlist-item" role="option">QA1BILLINGPLAN10</li>
   <li class="x-boundlist-item" role="option">Standard Mail</li>
   <li class="x-boundlist-item" role="option">Test Billing Plan Weekly AISIUI51</li>
   <li class="x-boundlist-item" role="option">Test Billing Plan Weekly GYUVKE85</li>
   <li class="x-boundlist-item" role="option">Test Billing Plan Weekly QVUDON97</li>
   <li class="x-boundlist-item" role="option">Test Billing Plan Weekly SKNWQI103</li>
   <li class="x-boundlist-item" role="option">Test Billing Plan Weekly SPUZRG6</li>
   <li class="x-boundlist-item" role="option">Test Billing Plan Weekly XUXMMA91</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

I need to use another option from the list each time.

I code in Java.

Comment: Please add your Java code as well.

Comment: What do you mean each time use other option?? Do you to select option from the list using with their text which may be different each time??

Comment: I mean that first time when script create account should be selected "QA1BILLINGPLAN01" option.
In second run should be "QA1BILLINGPLAN03"
And so on

Comment: So you mean you want to select option by passing these text Right??

Comment: Or you want automatically index would be increase one and select option by index??

Comment: Hi there; I've edited your question to rephrase some of the sentences into more standard english, and I also put some indentation into the html code. When you say you need to pick a different item each time - have you got a script you're working on which isn't yet working?